# How to update one value in the last row in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just wanted to know how should look my sql query to make an update of one value in the last row of my table. I tried to do this by query which is unfortunately not working:

```
UPDATE tableName SET food=888 WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableName)
```

I tried to use this query instead but it's incorrect aswell:

```
UPDATE tableName SET food=88 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

(I missed quotation marks in queries on purpose to make them clearly)

Comment: What's the problem with the 2nd query?

Comment: second query should work

Comment: Are you sure that the last entry in the table is going to be the one you are editing at the time the update statement runs? What about concurrency? It's safer to have an ID in mind that needs updating instead.  Anyway, I think your first query should have worked. What happens when it runs?

Comment: UPDATE `table` SET `column`='new-value' WHERE `id` = (SELECT max(id) FROM `table`)

Comment: @RohanKhude no, this is going to result in an error #1093

Comment: arghhh it was my fault, in second query, I put value into backtick escapes and that caused the problem, thanks everyone anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 2nd query works, I tested it in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6dc8/1)

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
    (`Id` int, `food` int)
;

INSERT INTO tableName
    (`Id`, `food`)
VALUES
    (1, 8)
;

UPDATE tableName SET food=88 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```